# confusion in output of C program for concatenation of two strings

Tags: c, output, concatenation, string-concatenation

So this is my code for appending string2 to string 1. Code works fine when I have added the line: `s1[null_index]='\0';`
but when i omit it adds the word 'road' one more time to the output...why is that? Why do I have to specify that the final value of null_index variabe is `'\0'`....shouldnt the computer already know this since it does when I declare and assign in the beginning?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
char s2[]="a lonely road";
char s1[]="Success is ";
    int l=strlen(s1);
    int null_index=l,i=0;
while(s2[i]!='\0')
{

s1[null_index]=s2[i];
i++;
null_index++;
}
s1[null_index]='\0'; 
printf("%s",s1);
}
```

Comment: Sorry. Your program is completely wrong. You are trying to write "off the end" of `s1`  where there is no memory allocated for you. Your actual question? Strings in C have to be 0 terminated.

Comment: You need to lear how to indent your code. Look at the samples in your C text book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the arrays you have are of a fixed size. Once initialized, any indexing beyond the null-terminator will be out of bounds and lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

If you want to append to `s1` then you need to explicitly set a size of the array, a size that fits both the strings (plus the terminator).

And when you append to `s1`, the very first iteration of your loop you overwrite the terminator. Since you then don't copy the terminator from `s2` you have to explicitly set the terminator of `s1` at the appropriate place.

Comment: so if i set a size that fits both strings...say 100...then this means that the '\0' will automatically be added at the end, right? on the other hand if i have not specified the size like this then the computer would not know where '\0' is since it has been overwritten. is my understanding right?

Comment: @AnasAziz The terminator will be "automatically" added because on initialization the unused parts of the array will be initialized to zero. But it's a good habit to *always* explicitly add the terminator yourself.

Answer (score 2):

`s1` is allocated only as much memory as `Success is` requires and when you try to do `s1[null_index]=s2[i];` you are inducing an undefined behavior.

Answer (score 2):

To begin with

```
char s2[]="a lonely road";
char s1[]="Success is ";
```

Will declare `s2` with size 14  and `s1` with size 12. Hence when you write characters more than 12 to `s1` you are invoking undefined behavior.

Change it to.

```
char s1[100]="Success is ";
```

---

To answer your question.

In `c`, strings are null(`\0`) terminated by definition. Hence `printf` will look for `\0` in the provided string to terminate the printing of `string`.

If the `string` does not contain `\0` character, it will go on printing the characters until it finds one eventually invoking the undefined behavior.